# Call A Function On ScrollExtend - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to call a function on scrollExtend. I need the code like below but its not working fine. How to make it work?

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('#scrollBox').scrollExtend(function() {
            //alert('scroll extend working');
            //functionCall();
        });
    }
);
```

But the actual code of scrollExtend is like below in which i dont know how to call a function on it,

```
jQuery('.scroll_container').scrollExtend({
    'target': 'div#scroll_items',
    'url': 'more_content.html',
    'newElementClass': 'list_item more_content'
});
```

Comment: why use `scrollExtend` if you simply want to specify a callback, just use `onScrollBeyond`

Comment: onScrollBeyond not get triggered when i scroll to the end. Do we need to include any jQuery file for using onScrollBeyond??

Answer (score 1):

I would use the built in function onScrollBeyond in JQuery.

Else there is a setting in scrollExtend that is called beforestart and onSuccess which both are callback variables which means you could put functions there like

```
$('#scrollBox').scrollExtend({  
  'target': 'div#scroll_items',   
  'beforeStart': myFunction,  
  'onSuccess': mySecondFunction  
});
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

As BeadFist said, you can simply use onScrollBeyond:

```
 $('.scroll_container').onScrollBeyond(functionCall);//if the function exists already, just pass a reference too it
$('.scroll_container').onScrollBeyond(function()
{
    //your function
});
```

Mind you, for both `scrollExtend` and `onScrollBeyond`, you need [the plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/scrollExtend), of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#scrollBox').scroll(function() {
   if($('#scrollBox').scrollTop() + $('#scrollBox').height() == $(parentElm).height()) {
       alert("bottom!");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using onScrollBeyond:

```
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('#scrollBox').onScrollBeyond(function() {
      //alert('scroll extend working');
      //functionCall();
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: onScrollBeyond not get triggered when i scroll to the end. Do we need to include any jQuery file for using onScrollBeyond??

Comment: @VinothBabu well yes, since you were using scrollExtend, I assumed that you included the [jQuery plugin](http://contextllc.com/tools/jQuery-infinite-scroll-live-scroll) though I have not used this myself.

Comment: I have included jQuery plugin already.. do i need to include separate file like jquer.scrollextend.js what we included for scrollextend ??

Comment: No but when scroll upto bottom. nothing happens. (i.e) i gave alert function. but it is not get triggered. :(

Comment: @VinothBabu hmm, I can't really say more without seeing your code, but [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Acsz8/) shows how to use it.